# how does trec eval calculate MAP?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

```
print "Running trec_eval script..."
N = len(y_pred_test)
df_submission = pd.DataFrame(index=numpy.arange(N), columns=['qid', 'iter', 'docno', 'rank', 'sim', 'run_id'])
df_submission['qid'] = qids_test
df_submission['iter'] = 0
df_submission['docno'] = numpy.arange(N)
df_submission['rank'] = 0
df_submission['sim'] = y_pred_test
df_submission['run_id'] = 'nnet'
df_submission.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, 'submission.txt'), header=False, index=False, sep=' ')
df_gold = pd.DataFrame(index=numpy.arange(N), columns=['qid', 'iter', 'docno', 'rel'])
df_gold['qid'] = qids_test
df_gold['iter'] = 0
df_gold['docno'] = numpy.arange(N)
df_gold['rel'] = y_test
df_gold.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, 'gold.txt'), header=False, index=False, sep=' ')
subprocess.call("/bin/sh run_eval.sh '{}'".format(output_dir), shell=True)
```

I have this code in tensorflow and it compiled successfully.
And the data in submission.txt is as below:(take qid as 33.1 for example)

```
33.1 0 12 0 0.27250546217 nnet
33.1 0 13 0 0.262122750282 nnet
33.1 0 14 0 0.292897969484 nnet
33.1 0 15 0 0.244421452284 nnet
33.1 0 16 0 0.00145227077883 nnet
33.1 0 17 0 0.264055848122 nnet
33.1 0 18 0 0.235591337085 nnet
```

The data in gold.txt is shown below:(take qid as 33.1 for example)

`33.1 0 12 1
33.1 0 13 1
33.1 0 14 1
33.1 0 15 1
33.1 0 16 0
33.1 0 17 0
33.1 0 18 0`

I think the MAP results should be calculated like this:
First, sort the prediction by score(which is 'sim') along with their labels.
So the sorted output should be:(only kept 2-3 digits after the decimal point for clear, the pattern is given out in {score, label} style)

0.29 1

0.27 1

0.264 0

0.262 1

0.24 1

0.23 0

0.00 0

So i think MAP should be: (1/1 + 2/2 + 3/4 + 4/5) / 5 = 0.71

but in submission.txt.treceval, it says *0.8875*, which i don't know how it gets.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, MAP is calculated as (1/1 + 2/2 + 3/4 + 4/5)/4.
And that is because in general you should divide the sum of p@(i) by total number of related documents not the value of largest i.
[image]